# Pass variable to a detail view controller using a table in UIViewController (not UITableViewController!!)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.3

I currently have 2 view controllers: `ViewController` and `DetailViewController`. Neither of them are Table View Controllers, they are both just View Controllers. However, I do have a table on `ViewController` which is otherwise working great. I want to segue/pass a variable to `DetailViewController` when a cell is selected.

Using the storyboard I set up a modal segue from the cell to `DetailViewController` with the identifier `toDetailView`.

I tried to use this method to pass my variable (in this example called `play`) from VC to DVC (via http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toDetailView"]) {

        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.play = [dataController objectInListAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

However I get an error: `Property 'tableView' not found on object type 'ViewController *'`. I think this is because it's not a Table View Controller? How can I get around this? Or is there another method I could use to segue and pass the variable using `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the ViewController, create a new property like that :

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

And `synthesize` it. Then, in Interface Builder, you should be able to assign the outlet to the tableview  you are using. This should do the trick

Comment: I tried that and it made my program crash on building. No particular error was given in the output to help me debug. I'm trying different approaches.

Comment: Crash when building ? GCC or LLVM ? There is something else wrong, cause this is the canonical way to do it. Post your sourcode please

Comment: I'm trying it again to make sure I didn't do something stupid the first time. Now I am getting the error that I have `Use of undeclared identifier 'dataController'` on the last line of code. I can edit my original post with more source code but I'm not sure which sections of the code are most useful for you to see.

Comment: How is `dataController` defined?  (If it's a property of the view controller, it may be as simple as `self.dataController`.)

Comment: I actually got this working, I had a lot of stuff wrong with my code, it would take too much space to post in the comment. But thanks for your help because the outlet was definitely needed!